# POST a SESSION variable on another page

Tags: php

When I use the code provided below everything works fine unless there is an apostrophe or other html special characters in the SESSION I am trying to pass in the value. I have tried both htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() with no success. please help.
thanks,
James

```
<?php
<form action='ashlyBlogBig2.php' method='POST'> 
    <input type='hidden' name='title'   value='{$_SESSION['title']}'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='time' value='{$_SESSION['time']}'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='blog' value='{$_SESSION['blog']}'/>
    <input type='submit' name='to you' class='productButtons' value='Read On. . . .'>
</form> ";
?>
```

Comment: Please show some sample data, the expected output and the actual output. And please define what "works fine unless" means exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ENT_QUOTES` as the second param to [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php), to be certain that both single and double quotes are encoded inside the variable.

```
echo  "<input type='hidden' name='blog' value='" . htmlentities($_SESSION['blog'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'/>"
```

Since `htmlentities()` is a function call, it cannot be interpolated inside a double-quoted string the way a variable, array element, or object property can.  You must close the currently open string and concatenate in the return of a function call.

The `ENT_QUOTES` flag to `htmlentities()` encodes both single and double quotes, making a string suitable for use inside an HTML attribute (which is already quoted).

Comment: I just tried this method, it worked! Why does the added double quotes and concatenation make this work? Thanks for help.

Comment: @JamesHowardHemsley I added a little more explanation above.